Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: /home/vsts/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a8ec627c377f5b2bd3147d8e9fe2cc58/transformed/jetified-.aar
I am trying to build an Android application developed in Java. The build was successful locally, but it's failing in the pipeline build. Locally, I am using Windows 11, and in the pipeline, I am using a Linux operating system. I am using Gradle 7.4 and AGP 7.3.1.
I have tried clearing the cache, and updating the Gradle version and Android Gradle plugin(AGP) version, still facing the same issue.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform .aar to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: /home/vsts/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a8ec627c377f5b2bd3147d8e9fe2cc58/transformed/jetified-.aar.
> zip END header not found

What I've already tried: cleaning the project, rebuilding the project, invalidating caches, deleting the .gradle folder, reinstalling Android Studio

My configuration is : Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) Version: 7.3.1
Local OS: Windows 11,
Pipeline OS: Linux (Azure DevOps),
Java Version: 1.8,
Build is successful locally but failing in the pipeline
